# MongoDB aggregate duplicates

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there an option to find Object values duplicates in different object keys with Mongo aggregate framework ? To be more clear, I show  my query and some input and expected output:

**My aggregation query:**

```
const Customer = require('../models/Customer');

const getDataDuplicates = (req, res) => {
  Customer.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          title:  "$title" ,
          salutation: "$salutation",
          firstName: "$firstName",
          lastName: "$lastName",
          companyName: "$companyName",
          business: "$business",
          street: "$street",
          city: "$city",
          postcode: "$postcode",
          email: "$email",
          phone: "$phone"
        },
        uniqueIds: {$addToSet: "$_id"},
        count: {$sum: 1}
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        count: {$gt: 1}
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {"count": -1}
    },
    {
      $project: {
        "_id": "$uniqueIds",
        "title": "$_id.title",
        "salutation": "$_id.salutation",
        "firstName": "$_id.firstName",
        "lastName": "$_id.lastName",
        "companyName": "$_id.companyName",
        "business": "$_id.business",
        "street": "$_id.street",
        "city": "$_id.city",
        "postcode": "$_id.postcode",
        "email": "$_id.email",
        "phone": "$_id.phone"
      },
    },
  ])

    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    }).catch((e) => {
    res.send(e)
  })
}
module.exports = {getDataDuplicates};
```

For now my query handles only one situation when all object data is the same. But what if :

1. Two Customers will have for example the same firstName, lastName, companyName and email, but other one will have for example same email, street and phone etc.

**Here example data input before aggregation :**

```
    {
        "_id": "6259715edaa388eb639b2ce5",
        "title": "Prof",
        "salutation": "Herr",
        "firstName": "Bartlomiej",
        "lastName": "Slapinski",
        "companyName": "ITSD",
        "business": false,
        "street": "sadasd",
        "city": "Krefeld",
        "postcode": "47805",
        "email": "mjacquet0@ucoz.rugg",
        "phone": "2132142143214214",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "246e9e89c29750f52974566b",
        "title": "Dr",
        "salutation": "Firma",
        "firstName": "Bartlomiej", // duplicate
        "lastName": "Slapinski", // duplicate
        "companyName": "ITSD", // duplicate
        "business": true,
        "street": "Gigstr. 24", 
        "city": "Egal", 
        "postcode": "47225", 
        "email": "mjacquet0@ucoz.rugg", //duplicate
        "phone": "2132142143",
        "__v": 0
    },
```

Above input shows that name, lastname, company Name and email are the same so the query results should look like this:

```
    {
        "_id": [
            "6259715edaa388eb639b2ce5",
            "246e9e89c29750f52974566b"
        ],
        "firstName": "Bartlomiej",
        "lastName": "Slapinski",
        "companyName": "ITSD",
        "email": "mjacquet0@ucoz.rugg",
    },
```

So the logic should look something like these:

```
Loop through $group and check if $email is same $or firstName $or and so on and so on ...
```

if anything is unclear please ask questions and let me know i will post more info, Thanks !

Comment: Could you please give an expected output for your input data?

Comment: @AlisettarHuseynli i've edited my question, hope its more clear now

Comment: I think we have some unclear points in this problem. Assume that you have duplicated one of the objects in your input data. Should your output be the intersection of all fields? In that case, you will have only one output object regardless of how much input you give.  As I understood you want to process input objects pairwise. And get all possible intersection pairs.

Comment: @AlisettarHuseynli what i've done till now i have separate manually set criteria for example: choose from select Input to find duplicates by email then choose by phone or choose by last name, and my question is how to write a query which will loop through all the objects values find there duplicates pairs and display them